# Cycle through bootstrap tooltip elements, show and hide them simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to cycle through `tooltipabble` elements, and show on each of them tooltip
for some period of time, hiding one that was previously shown.

Showing them is all good, but I have problem on how to hide the previous one.

I am using `bootstrap` tooltip('show') and tooltip('hide') methods, so I wrap element in `$()`

```
(function(){
    var i = 0;
    var tt = $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]');

    setInterval(function(){

        // if(oldTip) $(oldTip).tooltip('hide'); // not working

        var tip = tt[i++];
        $(tip).tooltip('show');

        // tried saving old instance here but that didn't work
        // oldTip = tip;

        if(i >= tt.length) i = 0;

    }, 2000);
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save a oldTip variable outside the setInterval callback. See in demo: http://jsfiddle.net/1vm90Lcx/

```
(function(){
var i = 0;
var tt = $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]');
var oldone;

setInterval(function(){

    if(oldTip) $(oldTip).tooltip('hide'); 

    var tip = tt[i++];
    $(tip).tooltip('show');
    oldTip = tip;

    if(i >= tt.length) i = 0;

}, 2000);
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(function () {
    var i = 0;
    var tt = $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]');

    setInterval(function () {

        // hide all tooltips
        tt.tooltip('hide');
        // show the one we want (use toggle - as show will compete with hide)
        $(tt[i++ % tt.length]).tooltip('toggle');

    }, 2000);
})();
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/billymoon/60e7ejj5/1/

Comment: This is the better answer.

Comment: most elegant solution I must admit, however I accepted the above one, because it clarified what was wrong in my original post.. thanks, and no hard feelings ;)

Comment: oh it does not work, only first cycle it is going good, next one is showing and immediately hiding each one of them..???

Comment: @branquito should work now - and has demo - I had not accounted for animation time of hiding, which continued to execute after the show function was called.

Comment: @BillyMoon This is great, just what I was looking for too. Is it possible for this to execute on say 5 seconds of user inactivity and then stop on interaction/mouse activity again?